# getting scratch and current workspace ArcGIS10 using Java

Tags: arcobjects, java

I'm trying to get the scratch and current workspaces returned as path names (Strings) using java in ArcGIS10.  however I can't seem to get anything returned.  I'm guessing it's to do with accessing the environments in Arc but the API is woeful.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late response, but here it is for the scratch workspace:

```
IScratchWorkspaceFactory scratchWSF=new ScratchWorkspaceFactory();          
IWorkspace scratch=scratchWSF.getDefaultScratchWorkspace();
String path=scratch.getPathName();
```